# OAuth 2.0 with a single server

Tags: api, authentication, oauth-2.0, server, restful-authentication

I have come to see that the OAuth 2.0 protocol calls for a "Web App Server" that has the APIs as well as a "OAuth 2" server that authenticates the user.  Though can this be done on a single server or are there specific reasons it MUST be done on two separate servers?

Can the authentication be a login API call on the single web server that returns an access token itself or will this be a faulty manner of authenticating?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The "Web App Server" - or Resource Server in OAuth 2.0 terminology - and the "OAuth 2" server - or Authorization Server in OAuth 2.0 terminology - can certainly live on the same server. The concept is meant to separate the authentication of the user (Resource Owner) and the authorization of the caller (Client) from the application itself in to a separate service (Authorization Server) but whether that separate service lives on the same box is irrelevant assuming you control both.

The authentication can be a login API call that returns an access token. Examples of that are the so-called Resource Owner Password Credentials grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.3) and the Client Credentials grant (https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-4.4).